# Code executes on Simulator but not on Device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

In the binding for one of my ViewControllers I have this code:

```
BindingSet.Bind(DateSelectBarItem)
          .For(v => v.TintColor)
          .To(vm => vm.HasDatesSelected)
          .WithConversion(new DateFilterButtonStateToTintColourConverter());
```

Where the `DateSelectBarItem` is a `UIBarButtonItem`.

This is the code for the converter:

```
public class DateFilterButtonStateToTintColourConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, UIColor>
{
    protected override UIColor Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ? ColourPalette.Orange : ColourPalette.Blue;
    }
}
```

Now the odd thing is that when I run this on the simulator, I can see that the binding works, the `HasDateSelected` property is accessed and the `Convert` method for the converter runs.

But then I deploy to the device, it doesn't work at all. In fact, when I debug off the device, the code doesn't even execute and no break points are hit.

Comment: probably a linking issue. Make sure your code isn't linked away by adding additional stuff to LinkerPleaseInclude.cs

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thanks man that was it exactly, this actually solved another issue I was having. Please can you add it as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linking issue. Usually when something works fine on a Simulator in Debug mode and does not work on an actual device. It is probably because the Linking process stripped some of your code out.

This is caused because the linker cannot detect when code is used through reflection, which MvvmCross relies on for bindings.

In order to hint the linker that the code is actually used, MvvmCross includes a `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs` file, where you can add additional includes, which use the constructors, methods and properties that you expect to be used in the rest of your code.

So for instance in your case described above, `DateSelectBarItem` has a property `TintColor`, which you are using in your binding. An example of adding a hint to the linker in the `LinkerPleaseInclude.cs`file would be:

```
public void Include(BarItem item)
{
    item.TintColor = Color.Red;
}
```

This should be enough to hint the linker to keep `TintColor`. You can do similar things with constructors and methods.